# Find the equation of the line tangent to the curve of the function $e^{x^2}$ in the point with coordinates $x=1$,$y=e$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Find  the equation of the line tangent to the curve of the function $e^{x^2}$ in the point with coordinates $x=1$,$y=e$.

I found that tis equation is $y=2ex-e$ Is this wrong?

Comment: you're absolutely right!!!

Comment: Yes/no questions such as these can also (and perhaps should) be asked in the chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics

Comment: When $y= e^{x^2}$ you must have  $\frac{y-e}{x-1}=y'(1)$ so you are right because you have well calculated $y'(1)$.

Comment: i am sorry about my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line tangent to a curve in the point $(x_0, y_0)$:
$$y = f'(x_0) (x-x_0)+f(x_0)$$
where $f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)$ and $f(x_0)=y_0$. Then, since in this case $f(x) = e^{x^2}$, we get $f'(x)= 2x e^{x^2}$. Therefore the equation of the tangent line is:
$$y=2e(x-1)+e=2ex-2e+e=2ex-e$$

So the answer is yes, you are right

Answer (score 1):

here dy/dx=2xy
at(1,e) , dy/dx=2e
therefore equation of tangent line at (1,e) 
y-e=2e(x-1)
y=2ex-e
Thanks